# Is there a way to hold up onSharedPreferenceChangeListener until last change?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In settings activity, I have multiple fields, once the user press save all these fields will be stored separately as key-value in sharedPreference.

The problem is every editor change e.g.

```
editor.putString(SERVER, server.toString());
```

will fire onSharedPreferenceChangeListener

While I only need to fire it after update all values.. 
Is there any way to achieve this requirement? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only a way to do that. You can put `editor.putString(SERVER, server.toString());` in runtime code, such as you pressing a button. Once the activity gets destroyed call `editor.commit();` within `onDestroy()` method, it will saves the value and fires `onSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. Simply, waiting for the user to close the activity first which means that users already changed all of their settings.

Note: please make sure that `editor` is an instance variable or make a field for it.

**EDIT**

Here's an example for you:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    // a field for preference
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        // for example, edit the value using a button at runtime
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editor.putString(SERVER, server.toString());
            }
        });
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        // call commit to save all changes
        editor.commit();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it is still will fire **onSharedPreferenceChangeListener** for every preference change statement

Comment: I completely edited my answer, it might helps you a lot. Please read again.

Comment: That's great, thanks!  but although it adopts all changes at once, **onSharedPreferenceChangeListener** _get called multiple times_ :l